# PInvoke FormatMessage Message ByRef lpBuffer As [String] Is Nothing

Tags: vb.net, pinvoke, wininet, kernel32

Declaring this function:

```
    <DllImport("kernel32.dll", EntryPoint:="FormatMessageW", SetLastError:=True, CharSet:=CharSet.Unicode, CallingConvention:=CallingConvention.StdCall)>
Public Shared Function FormatMessage(ByVal dwFlags As Integer,
                                     ByRef lpSource As IntPtr,
                                     ByVal dwMessageId As Integer,
                                     ByVal dwLanguageId As Integer,
                                     ByRef lpBuffer As [String],
                                     ByVal nSize As Integer,
                                     ByRef Arguments As IntPtr) As Integer
End Function
```

Based on the definition here: https://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32/FormatMessage.html

**Scenario**
I am currently PInvoking wininet.dll to perform FTP transactions against a server. If an error is encountered I get a error code back from **Err.LastDllError**. I have a function defined that gets the the dll error and returns a message based on the error code, however it is not working as expected. Here is the function that I use to throw dll errors:

```
Private Sub ThrowLastDllError()
    Dim iLastErrorID As Integer = Err.LastDllError
    Dim iMessageBuffer As IntPtr = Nothing
    Dim iModuleHandle As IntPtr = GetModuleHandle("wininet.dll")

    Dim sMessageBuffer As String = Nothing

    If iLastErrorID > 12000 And iLastErrorID < 12157 Then
        FormatMessage(FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_HMODULE Or
                     FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS Or
                     FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER,
                     iModuleHandle,
                     iLastErrorID,
                     0,
                     sMessageBuffer,
                     256,
                     Nothing)

        Debugger.Break()
        'TODO: Throw exception with error code message here
    End If
End Sub
```

Based on the technique described here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/wininet/appendix-c-handling-errors I am expecting to get some kind of string message based on the error code for this particular dll, for example if I get an error code of 12110 (ERROR_FTP_TRANSFER_IN_PROGRESS. Reference: https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/help/193625/info-wininet-error-codes-12001-through-12156) I would expect to get a message back (in variable sMessageBuffer) similar to the following if not the same "The requested operation cannot be made on the FTP session handle because an operation is already in progress.". However sMessageBuffer is never assigned a value and remains nothing. I can only assume I am misusing this technique somehow, I've tried various ways described on online forums and this site itself but I haven't been successful.

Comment: Try to remove the FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER flag, and pass a pre- allocated string, using the signature with a StringBuilder

Comment: FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER is fine but you need the arg to be a ByRef IntPtr. You then marshal the string manually. Finally you need to deallocate it with a call to Marshal.FreeHGlobal.

Comment: @SimonMourier I now get a AccessViolationException using the function with StringBuilder parameter, here's the implementation of that: https://pastebin.com/bdrEVZAm disregard the InfWinAPITools.* stuff, edit fail on my part.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan are you saying lpBuffer is meant to be an IntPtr data type as ByRef? This contradicts the documentation.

Comment: Are you ok with C# ?

Comment: @SimonMourier I'm restricted to using VB.Net

Comment: No, it does not contradict the documentation. *The function allocates a buffer large enough to hold the formatted message, and places a pointer to the allocated buffer at the address specified by lpBuffer. The lpBuffer parameter is a pointer to an LPTSTR; you must cast the pointer to an LPTSTR (for example, (LPTSTR)&lpBuffer).*

Comment: @DavidHeffernan okay, I changed that parameter to ByRef lpBuffer as IntPtr and it allocated {0} to my variable that I passed into the function call, which to me seems like it's still getting nothing back.

Comment: You aren't checking the return value for an error. I always recommend learning how to use a winapi function, especially a complex one like this, with native code first. Only when you truly understand the function should you translate to pinvoke.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here some sample code that works:

```
Sub Main()

    Dim h As IntPtr = LoadLibrary("wininet.dll") ' or GetModuleHandle ...
    Dim sb = New StringBuilder(1024)
    FormatMessage(Format_Message.FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_HMODULE Or Format_Message.FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS,
        h,
        12002,
        0,
        sb,
        sb.Capacity,
        Nothing)

    Console.WriteLine(sb) ' prints "The operation timed out"
   ' FreeLibrary, etc.
End Sub

Enum Format_Message
    FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS = &H200
    FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM = &H1000
    FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_HMODULE = &H800
End Enum

<DllImport("Kernel32", SetLastError:=True, CharSet:=CharSet.Unicode)>
Public Function FormatMessage(ByVal dwFlags As Format_Message, ByVal lpSource As IntPtr, ByVal dwMessageId As Integer, ByVal dwLanguageId As Integer, lpBuffer As StringBuilder, ByVal nSize As Integer, ByVal Arguments As IntPtr) As Integer
End Function

<DllImport("kernel32", SetLastError:=True, CharSet:=CharSet.Unicode)>
Public Function LoadLibrary(ByVal lpFileName As String) As IntPtr
End Function
```

Comment: Thank you, this gives me the correct result. I did not have ByVal as the parameter for lpSource and I did not omit ByRef for lpBuffer, as soon as I did that the code works as expected. The PInvoke documentation as far as I can see needs to be updated as I got the declaration from there (which is incorrect).

Comment: While my issue is resolved I am curious to how you came to this conclusion, was there something I missed in the documentation? Just wondering what troubleshooting steps you took for this particular issue so I can do the same thing in the future.

Comment: You could use FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER but it's more complicated from managed code IMHO. I just tried the pinvoke.net declaration, checked it crashes, just like you, so I changed the lpBuffer to byval as it's just a pointer, not a pointer to a pointer. BTW, FormatMessage is a very old function (from Windows NT day 1) with a nasty "swiss knife" interface.

Comment: @D.Foley ByRef IntPtr is correct if the callee is allocating the buffer. You seem to be having trouble believing that.